# How to hide payment method like COD and online payment ,with the selection of shipping methods like 'cash on delivery' or 'Prepaid ' in magento 1.9

Tags: php, magento, payment

I am using magento 1.9
I have two shipping methods Cash on delivery and another is Prepaid.
I want to hide the COD payment method if customer selects Prepaid shipping or 
if customer selects Prepaid shipping method--> COD payment method must be hidden like no selection

[image]

Please Let me know as immediate as possible

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify the Payment methods model class files from the directory app/code/core/Mage/Payment/Model/Method like Cashondelivery.php for Cash On Delivery payment method. To overwrite core files either you can create a new module to extend these payment method classes or copy these files to Local folder e.g. app/code/local/Mage/Payment/Model/Method. Then you need to add a new function in these files to check selected shipping methods and based on that you can show/hide that particular payment methods. I have added the function in below code for Cash On Delivery methods as below:-
class Mage_Payment_Model_Method_Cashondelivery extends Mage_Payment_Model_Method_Abstract
{

```
/**
 * Payment method code
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $_code  = 'cashondelivery';

/**
 * Cash On Delivery payment block paths
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $_formBlockType = 'payment/form_cashondelivery';
protected $_infoBlockType = 'payment/info';

/**
 * Get instructions text from config
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getInstructions()
{
    return trim($this->getConfigData('instructions'));
}
/* custom function to check shipping method and show/hide this payment methods*/
public function isApplicableToQuote($quote, $checksBitMask)
{
    if ($quote->getShippingAddress()->getShippingMethod() == 'flatrate_flatrate') {
        return false;
    }
    return parent::isApplicableToQuote($quote, $checksBitMask);
}
```

You need to find the shipping method code of your custom shipping method and replace them in the function with flatrate_flatrate code.

Comment: didn't work!!
 I am using
two shipping methods
1. s_method_premiumrate_ONLINE_PAYMENT
2.s_method_premiumrate_cashondelivery

and

payment methods:

Comment: Please send me website url.

Comment: It looks like you are using custom extensions for shipping and payment methods so needs to modify their classes. Please let me know their names.

Comment: the extension name is matrix rate premium extension